# Google Colab: No toolbar in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I just started using Colab. I copied the Tutorial notebook per the [Getting Started](https://course.fast.ai/start_colab.html) instructions and then opened it. This is what I see at the top of the page:

[image: missing toolbar screenshot]

I don't see the toolbar and there is no "Toggle Toolbar" option under the View menu. I've tried using Safari, Chrome, and Firefox - they all display the same behavior.

How do I make the toolbar visible?

Comment: The toolbar is visible in the screenshot. (It has the add code cell and add text cell buttons.) What are you trying to do, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @BobSmith All of the colab docs (and the Jupyter notebook documentation) show the toolbar like this: https://imgur.com/a/d9hlQvP).

Comment: Jupyter and Colab are distinct -- the screenshot you linked in your comment shows Jupyter rather than Colab. The screenshot linked in your original post shows Colab rather than Jupyter. Docs for Jupyter generally won't apply to Colab directly, although both have analogous concepts of code and markdown cells. Is there something in particular you were trying to do in Colab based on the Jupyter docs?

Comment: Ah... ok, thank you very much. I was following the Colab/FasiAI docs which specifically called out the toolbar - I just wanted to be certain I hadn't done something wrong.